# Use trusted SSL certificate with spring boot in pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, cloud-foundry

Im new to the topic of SSL certificates and i want to install my purchased SSL so that when users enter my site they wont see the untrusted certificate waring here are the steps i did so far

1. created a p12 file using the keytool
2. created a csr file from the file in step 1
3. uploaded the csr to my ssl vendor and after passing their verification of my domain, downloading the following files: .crt, .ca-bundle, .p7b files

i placed all the files (including the generated file by me) in the resources directory and added the following properties

```
server.ssl.key-store:classpath:myFile.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password:some_pass
server.ssl.keyStoreType:PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias:someAlias
```

i later ran the following command: keytool -importcert - trying to import the file i got from the ssl vendor to the file i created (.p12)

than i created my jar and uploaded it to pivotal cloud foundry but i still see the invalid certificate message

i dont know if i need to do something on the pivotal platform or something on the spring boot config

Answer (score 0):

The only way this would work is if you use a TCP route. With standard HTTP routes on Cloud Foundry, the traffic first hits a load balancer & then Gorouter. TLS termination is going to happen there, *not* at your application. If you use a TCP route, this will load balance at the TCP level and allow your application to perform the TLS termination directly.

That said, you really don't want to do that. the TCP route isn't likely to allow you to pick port 443, because a port can only be assigned to one application. That means only one application using TCP routes can have port 443. Also in most cases, platform operators are only allowing high numbered ports for TCP routes, which means no one would be able to pick 443. Long story short, you don't want your users to have to access your site as https://www.example.com:47385, so you don't want a TCP route.

---

To set this up properly with standard HTTP routes, you are going to need to work with your platform operations team. Together you will need to do the following:

1. Obtain the domain you'd like to use.
2. Obtain a load balancer. This needs to be configured to route traffic to the Gorouters in the foundation. You can skip this and use the existing load balancer, but that has implications[1] for step #6 below.
3. Configure DNS for your domain so that it routes to the load balancer in step #2.
4. Add the domain as a private or shared domain in CF.
5. Map a route to your application using the domain you created in step #3.
6. Add your TLS certificate & key to the load balancer [1].

When you've done all this, traffic to your domain will resolve to the IPs of your load balancers. Your user's browser will make an HTTPS request to the LB, which will terminate TLS (if it's an HTTP/layer-7 LB), and forward along to Gorouter (if there is a TCP/layer-4 LB, then TLS is terminated here), which in turn forwards along to your application (based on the route you mapped).

Your application will need to look at the `x-forwarded-for` and `x-forwarded-proto` headers to confirm if the request came in over HTTPS, since it is not terminating TLS directly.

[1] - The implication is with how the certificates get installed. With a separate LB, you add the cert to it and are done. If you are trying to reuse the platform LB, you will need to add the cert to the existing list of certs. In addition, if your platform operations team is using a TCP/layer-4 load balancer then TLS termination does not happen at the LB, it happens at Gorouter. This means you then have to load your TLS cert into the Gorouter, which requires a Bosh deploy and is more work. Modifying the platform LB also runs the risk of an error taking down the foundation. For those reasons and more, adding a separate LB for your app is usually the way to go.